# Unmarshal into a list of abstract elements

Tags: java, xml, list, jaxb, abstract

Short: I want to unmarshal a XML file into a list of abstract elements.
I will provide some short samples:
XML:

```
<Container>
    <Set>
        <A x="1"/>
        <B/>
        <Set>
            <C/>
            <D x="3"/>
        </Set>
        <E/>
    </Set>
</Container>
```

Java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlTransient
@XmlSeeAlso( {A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class, E.class, Set.class})
class Abs {

    private String x;

    public Abs() { x = null; }

    public String getX() { return x; }

    public void setX(String x) { this.x = x; }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
class A extends Abs { public A() {} }

@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
class B extends Abs { public B() {} }

@XmlRootElement(name = "C")
class C extends Abs { public C() {} }

@XmlRootElement(name = "D")
class D extends Abs { public D() {} }

@XmlRootElement(name = "E")
class E extends Abs { public E() {} }

@XmlRootElement(name = "Set")
class Set extends Abs {

    private List<Abs> elements;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<Abs> getElements() { return elements; }

    public void setElements( List<Abs> elements ) { 
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Container")
class Container {

    Set main;

    public Container() { this.main = null; }

    @XmlElement(name = "Set")
    Set getMain() { return main; }

    void setMain(Set main) { this.main = main; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Container c = (Container) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint on the printline, and at that point, my "c" has a null list.
How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all the possible values of the elements property are subclasses of `Abs` I would use `@XmlElementRef`.

```
@XmlElementRef
public List<Abs> getElements() { return elements; }
```

`@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` will give you the same behaviour but comes with the following limitations:

- An unexpected element is going to cause an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Element` to be instantiated and JAXB will attempt to put it in your `List`.
- You wont' be able to map another field/property in that class with `@XmlAnyElement`.

Comment: For some reason,
`@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` works, and the pair 
`@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElementRef` doesn't. But I know who you are and I also know you can't be wrong about jaxb, so I will look further into this.

Comment: @AlinValentin - Just tried my answer out in code and realized my original answer had the `@XmlElementWrapper` still in there which was wrong.  Once I removed it everything worked, answer has been updated to reflect this change.

Comment: Confirmed! It works as intended with either your or @Xstian's method. I will use yours instead so it won't attempt to add a `org.w3c.dom.Element` to my list in case of bad input.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Set.java` in ...

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;

public class Set extends Abs {

    private List<Object> elements;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public List<Object> getElements() { return elements; }

    public void setElements( List<Object> elements ) { 
        this.elements = elements;
    }

}
```

Comment: For this use case `@XmlElementRef` would be better than `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27507292/383861

Comment: Thanks, Xstian! It worked. I would only like to add that in my practical example I had to keep the `@XmlRootElement(name = "Set")` tag in order to be able to cast the object to a `Set` once again.

Comment: @AlinValentin it was a pleasure to help you :)